# How to solve $y'=\frac {4x-6y-4}{-2x+3y+1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

We have this: 
$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {4x-6y-4}{-2x+3y+1}$$

I solved task, I got this:
$$ 32x-16c-3ln|-8x-12y+7|+8x-12y-7$$,
but I need to get the equation for y. How do I do that?

Comment: Please try to improve your question by using mathjax, giving context, show us the steps of your work,...

Comment: Not all  Differential Equations have explicit form solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=\dfrac {(4x-6y-4)}{(-2x+3y+1)}$$
Substitute $z=-2x+3y+1$
$$\frac 13 {(z'+2)}=-2\dfrac {(z+1)}{z}$$
It's separable:
$$\dfrac {zdz}{z+3/4}=-8dx$$
$$4z- 3 \ln |4z+ 3|=-32x+C$$
You end with an implicit form for $y$. 
$$4y-  \ln |12y-8x+ 7|+8x=C$$